# Xamarin Forms - How to write typeof() in XAML?

Tags: forms, xaml, xamarin, constructor, datatemplate

The xamarin forms class `DataTemplate` recieves a parameter with `Type` in ctor.

```cs
public class DataTemplate : ElementTemplate, IDataTemplateController
{
    public DataTemplate(Type type);      
    ...
}
```

How to pass the type of a specific class to a ctor in XAML? In c# I would write `new DataTemplate(typeof(DeviceViewModel))`. But I have to write this in XAML.

Pseudo code:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <x:Arguments>
            <typeof(viewModels:DeviceViewModel)/>
    </x:Arguments>
    <myControls:MyCustomControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**EDIT**

To make my goals more clear I created a derived example. Let's say there is following structure:

- Picture
- Music
- Document

  - txt
  - pdf
  - xml

My List contains these elements. Every of this type has to be handled in own `DataTemplate`. In my case the items are quite complex so thats why I create a ViewModel for each Item. In code it could look like this:

```cs
public abstract class BaseViewModel
public class PictureViewModel : BaseViewModel
public class MusicViewModel : BaseViewModel
public class DocumentViewModel : BaseViewModel

/* My List full of different ViewModels*/
List<BaseViewModel> itemList;
```

Now I create a `TemplateSelector` which holds other `TemplateSelector`. It calls the right one based on view model type:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyApp.ViewModels;

namespace MyApp.TemplateSelectors
{
    public class MyItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplateSelector PictureTemplateSelector { get; set; }
        public DataTemplateSelector MusicTemplateSelector { get; set; }
        public DataTemplateSelector DocumentTemplateSelector { get; set; }

        public DataTemplateSelector DefaultTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            switch (item)
            {
                case PictureViewModel vm:
                    return PictureTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(item, container);
                case MusicViewModel vm:
                    return MusicTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(item, container);
                case DocumentViewModel vm:
                    return DocumentTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(item, container);
                default:
                    return DefaultTemplate.SelectTemplate(item, container);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML all the assignment happens:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PictureDefaultTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
       <Image Source="{Binding FilePath}"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MusicDefaultTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
       <Button Text="Play this!"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DocumentDefaultTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
       <Label Text="show filename at least"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- The DocumentTemplateSelector handles file extensions differently -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTxtTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
        <Label Text="This is a text file"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyPdfTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
        <Label Text="This is a pdf file"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyXmlTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
        <Label Text="This is a xml File"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>

<!--provide specific template selectors with initiated datatemplates-->
<templateSelectors:PictureTemplateSelector x:Key="pictureTemplateSelector" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource PictureDefaultTemplate}"/>
<templateSelectors:MusicTemplateSelector x:Key="musicTemplateSelector" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource MusicDefaultTemplate}"/>
<templateSelectors:DocumentTemplateSelector x:Key="documentTemplateSelector" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DocumentDefaultTemplate}"
                                                                     TxtTemplate="{StaticResource MyTxtTemplate}"
                                                                     PdfTemplate="{StaticResource MyPdfTemplate}"
                                                                     XmlTemplate="{StaticResource MyXmlTemplate}"/>

<!--provide superior template selector with other template selectors -->
<templateSelectors:MyItemTemplateSelector x:Key="myItemTemplateSelector"
                                          PictureTemplateSelector="{StaticResource pictureTemplateSelector}"
                                          MusicTemplateSelector="{StaticResource musicTemplateSelector}"
                                          DocumentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource documentTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Last bind MyItems (objects of type `BaseViewModel`) and set superior template selector. This is where I set the `CachingStrategy` to `RecycleElementAndDataTemplate`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myItemTemplateSelector}"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"/>
```

The Exception is thrown in DocumentTemplateSelector.

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyApp.ViewModels;

namespace MyApp.TemplateSelectors
{
    public class DocumentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate TxtTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate PdfTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate XmlTemplate { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            var doc = (DocumentViewModel)item;
            switch (doc.FileExtension)
            {
                case "txt":
                    return TxtTemplate; // Exception
                case "pdf":
                    return PdfTemplate; // Exception 
                case "xml":
                    return XmlTemplate; // Exception
                default:
                    return DefaultTemplate; // Exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following exception is thrown:

> System.NotSupportedException: RecycleElementAndDataTemplate requires DataTemplate activated with ctor taking a type.

@IvanIčin @G.hakim I'm not worried that the default mechanism is not working but after studying the xamarin forms code from github I see no other solution to make it work without passing the type in `DataTemplate` ctor.

**Update: new Xamarin Forms enhancement proposal**

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7060

Above enhancement would solve my request.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that i do not understand the reason to do so

Comment: If I manage to pass the type, the ctor `internal ElementTemplate(Type type) : this()` is called, where the `CanRecycle` prop will be set to true. If `CanRecycle` is set to true the `ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElementAndDataTemplate` will work properly. (See [DataTemplateSelector Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Core/DataTemplateSelector.cs)

Comment: @Crunch, you've got something wrong, see my answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure that should work directly

Comment: See my edit for clarification

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Crunch?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Instead of initilazing it in XAML I do it in the templateSelector `public class DocumentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
 {
  private DataTemplate TxtTemplate { get; } = new DataTemplate(typeof(TxtTemplate)); private DataTemplate PdfTemplate { get; } = new DataTemplate(typeof(PdfTemplate)); private DataTemplate XmlTemplate { get; } = new DataTemplate(typeof(XmlTemplate));`